# Craps Game JAVA - Input Validation Ignored?

Tags: java, validation, class, input, do-while

This is my first question I asked here. I am currently in CSCI 2911 in for a lab, we have to program a basic Craps game. Everything was working, until I added a simple betting system. Once I implemented it, it doesn't work.

***Here's the code for my java classes:***

**Main class:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rjohncraps;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Randall
 */
public class RJohnCraps {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Game Object
        Game g = new Game ();
        // Win Initalization
        int wins = 0;
        // Money Initlization
        int money = 0;
        // Bet Amount Initialization
        int bet = 0;
        // GameInput Initialization
        String gameInput = " ";

        System.out.println("Want to play a game of Craps? (y/n)");
        gameInput = input.nextLine();

        // If gameInput is yes or no
        switch (gameInput) {
            case "Y":
            case "y":
            case "Yes":
            case "yes": //If yes.

                // Game do-while
                do {
                    do { // Keep asking until bet is more or equal to zero
                        System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
                        bet = input.nextInt();
                    } while (bet <= 0);

                    // return character in play() [Game.java] to char result
                    char result = g.play();

                    switch (result) {
                        case 'W': // If Wins
                            System.out.println("You won!");
                            wins = wins + 1; // Add One Win to Win Count
                            money = money + bet; // Add Bet Amount to Total Money Amount
                            break;
                        case 'L': // If Loses
                            System.out.println("You lose!");
                            money = money - bet; // Deduct Bet Amount to Total Money Amount
                            break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (y/n)"); // Ask to play again

                    gameInput = input.nextLine();  

                // If gameInput = yes, then it will repeat
                } while (gameInput.equals("y") || gameInput.equals("Y"));

                // If gameInput = no
                System.out.println("Your total wins is "+wins+" wins.");

                // It total money is less than zero.
                if (money < 0) {
                    // If it's zero, then it's a negative, so multiply money by -1 to be positive
                    money = money * -1;
                    System.out.println("You owe "+money+" dollars.");

                } else if (money > 0) { // If total money is more than zero
                    System.out.println("You earned "+money+" dollars.");

                } else { // If total money is zero.
                    System.out.println("You earned nothing.");
                }

                break;

            // If Don't want to play    
            case "N":
            case "n":
            case "No":
            case "no":

                // Print a nice message
                System.out.println("Okay, have a nice day!");
                break;
            // If Default, Print Invalid Message                
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Word");

        }

    }

}
```

**Game class:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rjohncraps;

/**
 *
 * @author Randall
 */
public class Game {
    // Int Variables (set to private)
    private int result;
    private int point;

    // Craps Play
    public char play() {
        // Dice Object from [Dice class]
        Dice d = new Dice();
        // Blank Char
        char blank = ' ';

        // return int from rollTwoDice() to int result
        result = d.rollTwoDice();

        // Print the results from the Dice Rolls
        System.out.print(result+", ");

        // If First Roll is 2,3,12
        if (result == 2 || result == 3 || result == 12) {
            // Return L char
            return 'L';
        }

        // If First Roll 7 and 11
        else if (result == 7 || result ==11) {
            // Return W char
            return 'W';

        // If neither 2,3,12,7,11
        } else {
            // Assigned Result to Point variable
            point = result;

            // Loop until Result equals 7 or Point (First Roll)
            do {
                // return integer from rollTwoDice() to result variable
                result = d.rollTwoDice();
                // print result
                System.out.print(result+", ");
            } while (result != 7 && result != point);

            // if result equals 7
            if (result == 7) {
                // Return char L
                return 'L';
            }

            // if result equals point (first roll)
            if (result == point) {
                // return W char
                return 'W';
            }

        }

        return blank;

    }
}
```

**Dice class:** (Since I cannot post more than 2 links, I will post the code for Dice class here, since it's the shortest).

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rjohncraps;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author Randall
 */
public class Dice {
    // Int Variable for dice one, dice two, and sum of d1 and d2
    private int d1;
    private int d2;
    private int sum;

    // Random object
    Random bag = new Random();

    // Rolling Dice Method
    public int rollTwoDice() {
        // Sum of Two Dice Initialization
        int sum = 0;

        // Generate random numbers for dice one and dice two
        d1 = bag.nextInt(6)+1;
        d2 = bag.nextInt(6)+1;

        // Calculate the sum of dice 1 and dice 2
        sum = d1 + d2;

        // Return sum
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Here is what's going on (The Problem):**

When I run the code (from the main class),
First it will ask if I want to play Craps, in which I will type "y" from my keyboard.

Then it will ask how much I want to bet, in which I put in a integer amount that is positive. for instance, 100.

After that it will print the result from the dice rolls, i got 8, 9, 8. If you know the game of Craps, that means I won.

It suppose to say "Do you want to play again? (y/n)," in which I suppose to type either "y" or "n", but instead it will ignore the keyboard input part, and it will just print the total wins I got and the amount I earned.

Here's what the output looks like:

```
Want to play a game of Craps? (y/n)
y
How much do you want to bet?
100
8, 9, 8, You won!
Do you want to play again? (y/n)
// I suppose to type something in the keyboard, 
// but it skips that and just prints the results.
Your total wins is 1 wins.
You earned 100 dollars.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 14 seconds)
```

I don't know what's going on, it seems like the do while that labeled (Commented "Game Do-While" doesn't seem to work. What do you guys think? I have no idea.

If you need more information, just let me know!

Comment: @Arc676

yes, i am using Scanner for keyboard input. I do have duplicate of 'gameInput = input.nextInt();' 

Pardon for my lack of vocabulary.

Is this not allowed? Do I have to add a new Scanner question?

Comment: Did the answers on that other question help you?

Comment: @Arc676

What do you mean? I added a new Scanner question, and it didn't work. I added the code to the original post.

Comment: What I and the other commenter mean is that sometimes users post their questions on StackOverflow either without doing the appropriate amount of research or simply accidentally missing a result that actually solves their question. On SO, we solve this by marking such posts as "duplicates". I'm simply suggesting that maybe your problem is the same as that in some other posts. Did any of the answers in the links the other commenter and I provided help you?

Comment: @Arc676

Sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't see the link in your first comment, Arc. 

The linked question (linked by RC) definitely answered my question and problem. 

I didn't think it was a scanner problem. Never had this problem before when working on previous labs. Thanks for the help, and sorry for accidentally duplicated an answered question.